# Should I remove vendor prefixes?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

I have a website which I support as far as IE8, no further.

When I first launched the site, I decided to use CSS vendor prefixes for CSSs elements such as border-radius, box-shadow etc. I did this from a complete noob standpoint.

However, is a better approach not to use them and simply let browsers catch up rather than patch up for the sake of uniformity?

Comment: Give **[Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)** a look.

Comment: Are you asking if there're tools to patch standard CSS and make it cross browser? Or are you asking if you should let your site look ugly in legacy browsers? In the first case, you should edit the question and make it more clear. (In the second case, of course, it doesn't make much sense to ask strangers about it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you shouldn't remove *all* of them, however you may as well remove the ones which are no longer required.

### How can I find out which prefixes are no longer required?

[Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/) is a great resource for checking browser support for various CSS, HTML and JavaScript features. If you perform a search for `box-sizing`, for instance, it will tell you that all modern browsers have *partial support* for this and that Firefox requires the `-moz-` prefix. You can also view all of the CSS support tables on just one page [here](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS).

### How can I clarify that the prefixes are no longer required?

There are a couple of online resources which display information about browser usage. An example of this is [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/). StatCounter offers browser version statistics which can be filtered on time. If we look at the [last 3 months](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201307-201309), we can guestimate that we should still aim to support Firefox 20+, Chrome 25+, IE 8+ and Safari 5.1+.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just keep your vendor prefixes for now - this still remains professional practice - those browsers who don't need them, will simply ignore them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get rid of prefixes, one of the solutions you can try is [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/). It's a javascript plugin which loops through your stylesheets and, according to current browser removes the unused ones.
Although I didn't test it, I think it will definetely **lower the performance**.

You can also remove prefixes for properties which doesn't have a signifact meaning for functionality and/or user experience, like `border-radius`, `box-shadow` etc. You would have to test each element how it behaves without these properties. E.g. you have a button with `border-radius: 4px`. In a browser which doesn't support border-radius it will simply have rough corners. You must only consider if its worth sacrificing.

Answer (score 1):

Our approach is to drop those which aren't needed.

border-radius
box-shadow

box-sizing (soon? firefox still uses it. Noted by @James Donnelly)

opacity (not a prefix, but no need for the ms-filter thingie)
inline-block (same here, no need for inline+zoom fix)

Comment: Worth noting that Firefox still requires the `-moz-` prefix on `box-sizing`. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Comment: You can drop all other prefixes for `box-sizing` though. In fact, the *only* other prefix is `-webkit-`, so yeah, just drop that.