# Browser support to CSS3 and the vendor prefix

Tags: css

Its really annoying to have to deal with all CSS3 vendor prefixes. Is this necessary in the long run, or a temporary fix? How long i will need to maintain it in my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421180/should-i-remove-vendor-prefixes

Comment: so the short answer is keep then? or use a thrid javascript library...

Comment: If you plan to support legacy web browsers, keep the prefixes. It depends on your own/customer needs.

Comment: well... yes. Welcome to the web world. Go code native if you don't want to deal with variety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea would be to create all the vendor prefixed stuff using LESS or SASS mixins like this:

```
.box-shadow (@string) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @string;
    -moz-box-shadow:    @string;
    box-shadow:         @string;
}
```

That way once it is save to omit a prefix you can just remove it from your mixin and all the generated CSS will never contain it again.

You might also want to check this:

- http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/which-vendor-prefixes-are-needed/
- http://css3generator.com/ (what they don't generate is usually save to omit)
- http://caniuse.com/